# Prove $(1+ \tan{A}\tan{2A})\sin{2A} = \tan{2A}$.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove the following statement
$$ (1+ \tan{A}\tan{2A})\sin{2A} = \tan{2A}. $$
On the left hand side I have put the value of $\tan{2A}$ and have then taken the LCM.
I got $\sin{2A}\cos{2A}$. How do I proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

$$\text{LHS}= \\ \tan 2A  \left\{{1\over \tan2A} +\tan A\right\}\sin 2A \\ = \tan2A \left\{\frac{\cos 2A}{\sin 2A} + \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}\right\}\sin 2A \\= \tan2A \left\{\frac{\cos 2A\cos A + \sin2A \sin A}{\cos A}\right\} \\= \tan 2A \left\{\frac{\cos(2A -A)}{\cos A}\right\} \\ =\text{RHS}$$

Comment: But how does this prove?

Comment: @asto: Is it okay, now?

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong here??

Comment: I didnt do that

Comment: It is correct. Thanks

Comment: @asto; I've not meant that for you. BTW, did it help?

Comment: @user36790 I downvoted due to a terrible first attempt at an answer. Since your edit you've made it the best on offer IMO and I have upvtoted you again. Shame I can't give a +2! Cheers.

Comment: The last step is not obvious. You should calculate it out. Why is $cos(2A)cos(A)+sin(2A)sin(A)=cos(A)$ ?

Comment: @Autolatry: I've been acclimatized with PSE; there if you answer a homework question, you only have to give hints. It is also bit homework like; so I just did an intermediary-step which eventually could be worked out to get RHS. However, all is well that ends well:)

Comment: @user36790 I agree with you, from what I saw I couldn't see how it was a hint but that could be my failure. Anyway you've netted to zero with me! All the best.

Comment: @Peter: Okay I would edit it but I don't think it is essential ; after all if OP asks about multiple angle; he is bound to know compound angles formulae:|

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& (1 + \tan A \tan(2A))\sin(2A) \\
= & \left(1 + \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}\frac{\sin(2A)}{\cos(2A)}\right)\sin(2A)\\
= & \left(1 + \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}\frac{2\sin A\cos A} 
{\cos(2A)}\right)\sin(2A) \\
= & \left(1 + \frac{2\sin^2 A}{\cos(2A)}\right)\sin(2A) \\
= & \frac{\cos(2A) + 2\sin^2 A}{\cos(2A)}\sin(2A) \\
= & \frac{1 - 2\sin^2 A + 2\sin^2 A}{\cos(2A)}\sin(2A) \\
= & \frac{\sin(2A)}{\cos(2A)} \\
= & \tan(2A)
\end{align}

Comment: In 4th step,where did the cos A go?

Comment: It was a typo, I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$LHS=(1+\tan A\tan2A)\sin 2A$$  $$=\left(1+\tan A\frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan ^2A}\right)\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan ^2A}$$
$$=\left(\frac{1-\tan^2A+2\tan^2 A}{1-\tan ^2A}\right)\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan ^2A}$$
$$=\left(\frac{1+\tan^2A}{1-\tan ^2A}\right)\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan ^2A}$$
$$=\frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan ^2A}$$ $$=\tan 2A=RHS$$

Answer (score 1):

So this is equivalent to $$\sin 2A=\tan2A \left(1-\sin2A \tan A\right)$$

And $$1-\sin 2A\tan A=1-2\sin^2A=\cos 2A$$ so that everything works out (using $\sin 2A=2\sin A\cos A$ and $\cos 2A=1-2\sin^2A$)

Answer (score 1):

Noting that
$$\cot \theta\tan\theta=1$$
We have
$$(1+\tan A\tan 2A)\sin 2A = (1+\tan A\tan 2A)\sin 2A\cot 2A\tan 2A$$
Now just show that 
$$(1+\tan A\tan 2A)\sin 2A\cot 2A = 1$$
:)